# Rails get tasks based on previous selection

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

A bit of background - I'm working on a timesheet app that has projects and a project has time entries. When creating a time entry I have a select field which you use to select which project the time entry is related to. This all works fine.

Next I have added a tasks model, tasks belong to projects and a project has many tasks.

In my time entry form after selecting a project I then want to have another select field which has the tasks that are related to the project selected previously.

project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :time_entries
  has_many :tasks
end
```

task.rb

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

time_entry.rb

```
class TimeEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Time entry form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @time_entry do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :hours %>
  <%= f.input :project_id, as: :select, collection: @projects %>
  <%= f.input :task_id, as: :select, collection: Project.find(3).tasks %>
  <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

At time moment I'm just passing in an id but I want this id to be updated based on the project that I select first.

Any help / pointing in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need js event which will trigger an ajax request to the server to get all the tasks with that project id and add the response to the task's select.

Comment: Thanks I thought I might need to do something like that. Any idea where I can find a good tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: here is what looks like a pretty comprehensive tutorial: [http://roseweixel.github.io/blog/2015/07/05/integrating-ajax-and-rails-a-simple-todo-list-app/](http://roseweixel.github.io/blog/2015/07/05/integrating-ajax-and-rails-a-simple-todo-list-app/).